# Memory isn't deallocated - ActiveX control (.NET/C#) used in an MFC application

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, mfc, activex

I have a memory problem with a COM/OLE/ActiveX component. But I don't know more than the basics of ActiveX... I'm reaching out to the ActiveX experts here - I'd be VERY grateful for some help!!

I'm doing some maintenance on an old MFC project (a Win32 application) for a customer. The application uses a large ActiveX control - developed in .NET/C# by another group. The control is displayed in container windows (CFormView). Let's say that the Win32 application uses about 10MB and the .NET control 100MB:

1. I start the Win32 application - the process uses 10MB
2. I start a container window with the ActiveX control - the process uses 110MB
3. The container and its ActiveX control is closed/deleted - the process uses 110MB
4. I start a new container with the ActiveX control - **the process uses 210MB**

The memory isn't freed when the container window and its control is deleted. Perhaps the control is still running. After a couple of iterations, the memory consumption gets out of hand.

The ActiveX control is displayed using an ordinary CWnd object. When the container has been created, the control is created with a call to CWnd::CreateControl(). The application calls methods with CWnd::InvokeHelper(), and events from the control is handled via an event sink map. This works/appears-to-work fine. The applications does not import the TLB file. It creates the control based on it's registered name (linked to the control's DLL), and it uses IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames() to get the dispid of the methods to invoke.

The control has no "persistence"; we want it to deallocate completely when the dialog is closed. There can be two container windows with the control open simultaneously - the controls should not interfere with each other.

There is no code specifically deactivating/closing ActiveX. The CWnd object gets deleted before destroying/deleting the container. That is usually enough for other types of controls (e.g. a CEdit or a CComboBox); the class destructor destroys the window and deallocates all resources.

There is a lot of documentation about ActiveX, but it's quite confusing if you aren't an expert... Aren't deleting the CWnd object enough to stop the ActiveX control from running and deallocate everything? Should we call some other method before deleting the CWnd object?

Or could this be some error in the ActiveX control - what should I tell the .NET developers? Could they have missed something?

An ideas? I could read and test for ten days without getting any wiser, alas... :-(

/Anders from Sweden

Comment: Verifying that you do have a memory leak is pretty challenging when the CLR enters the picture. It will aggressively use memory resources and only relinquish those resources when memory pressure rises. If you only look at memory usage a well-behaved .NET application is indistinguishable from one that leaks resources.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for your input! Well, I'm not sure this is a memory leak, really. It's more like the ActiveX control isn't closed. When we delete the CWnd object, we want the ActiveX component hosted in it to disappear completely - deallocate everything, unload the DLL. But all the memory the component has been using is still there. So something isn't right. Is it something I should do in MFC, or something the .Net developers could have missed?

Comment: I don't know how the .NET hosting is implemented internally. In a previous project I hosted the CLR and it was impossible to unload a .NET assembly without tearing down the entire AppDomain. Maybe that's just how things work out in practice, although there could still be an issue in your code that fails to decrement the reference count on the ActiveX control. To verify this you could try to add a `while (pObk->Release())` loop to your shutdown code.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, there isn't any shutdown code. MFC has support for COM/ActiveX - you just use CreateControl() instead of Create() for a CWnd object. Then you get the InvokeHelper() and GetControlUnknown() helpers. And when the ActiveX component is hosted by the CWnd, you expect it to be torn down by the CWnd destructor, don't you? (Which calls DestroyWindow().) This works for all the regular controls. So there isn't really a pointer to Release(). :-( And the control disappears from the container windows; it's just seems to continue to run in the background somehow.

Comment: I assume that `GetControlUnknown` gets you an interface pointer to the ActiveX control, which allows you to indirectly retrieve the reference count (by calling `Release`). I believe there's also preprocessor symbol you can define that monitors ATL's (and possibly MFC's) reference counts. Another route to analyze or verify that there is an issue is WinDbg with the SoS extension. It provides lots of tools to dig into.NET's internals.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, GetControlUnknown() returns an IUnknown pointer. It is not reference counted, though. (It says so explicitly in the MFC documentation.) But you're right - I can use it to see if there seems to be some sort of "reference leak"! Especially after the CWnd destructor. I'm hoping I don't have to dig too deeply into the .Net internals; I'm no expert, and the ActiveX control is developed by another group...

Comment: [No one supports Active X anymore](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/)? Why are you using an out date technology?